# How to build this specific JSON Format with the given input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving the following JSON from back end

Right now there are two strike prices 6000 and 7000 and CE and PE open interest values for each strike price

```
[{
    "CE": "601650",
    "strike_pr": "6000",
    "PE": "1196350"
}, {
    "CE": "2553975",
    "strike_pr": "7000",
    "PE": "6069025"
}]
```

I am trying to generate a google visulization bar chart with this values as shown in this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7wYP2/453/

Could you please how can i build below format JSON Array form the above JSON

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['STRIKE_PR', 'CE', 'PE'],
        ['6000  ',  601650,   1196350],
          ['7000',  2553975,   6069025]
    ]);
```

Comment: `Object.keys()`, `[].map`, and `function pluck(o){"use strict"; return o[this];}` are almost all you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**Note:** *This answer assumes all objects will have same properties.*

#### @Dandavis's suggestion

```js
var data = [{
    "CE": "601650",
    "strike_pr": "6000",
    "PE": "1196350"
}, {
    "PE": "6069025",
    "CE": "2553975",
    "strike_pr": "7000",
}];

var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

var result = data.map(function(o){
  return keys.map(function(k){
    return o[k];
  });
});

result.unshift(keys);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,4) + "</pre>");
```

#### Array.forEach + Array.push

```js
var data = [{
    "CE": "601650",
    "strike_pr": "6000",
    "PE": "1196350"
}, {
    "CE": "2553975",
    "strike_pr": "7000",
    "PE": "6069025"
}];

var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

var result = [];
result.push(keys);

data.forEach(function(o){
  var _tmp = [];
  keys.forEach(function(k){
    _tmp.push(o[k])
  });
  result.push(_tmp);
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,4) + "</pre>");
```

#### Array.map + Array.unshift

```js
var data = [{
    "CE": "601650",
    "strike_pr": "6000",
    "PE": "1196350"
}, {
    "CE": "2553975",
    "strike_pr": "7000",
    "PE": "6069025"
}];

var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

var result = data.map(function(o){
  var _tmp = [];
  keys.forEach(function(k){
    _tmp.push(o[k])
  });
  return _tmp;
});

result.unshift(keys);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,4) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Even I updated my answer to use map, but your code is way too compact.

Comment: another map will dispense of the forEach/push combo (with a side of temp var). just return the map of the keys w/o the push()... generally, it best not to use `var` at all in array methods if you don't need to... your code is fine to be sure, but things can always be tweaked...